# Objective C - links to buttons and labels

Tags: objective-c

My classmate and I tried to learn how to link the code with buttons and labels. But it keeps saying "Incomplete implementation" error.

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

-(IBAction) btClickMe:(id)sender {
    lbTitle.text = @"Hello!";
}

-(IBAction) btWelcome:(id)sender{
    lbTitle.text = @"Welcome";
}

-(IBAction) btGo:(id)sender{
    lbTitle.text = txtName.text;
}

-(IBAction) btTryMe:(id)sender{
    if (x == 0) {
        lbTitle.text = @"Bye! Bye!";
        x = 1;
    } else {
        lbTitle.text = @"Welcome!";
        x = 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Incomplete implementation usually means you've declared that your class implements a method in your header, but you don't provide that method in your implementation.  This can also apply when you declare that your class conforms to a protocol with required methods.

Comment: If you declare your class implements a method but it doesn't actually implement that method, either the declaration is wrong and you should remove it, or the declaration is right and you should implement the method.  Post your interface file and you'll get more specific help.